# Hold button for a Slot machine in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm constructing a Slot Machine game in JavaScript, but i'm having trouble with the hold button. I'd like to implement a Hold button, that locks a chosen reel, but it's not quite working out for me! Here's what i got so far:

```js
var arr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];

function getNumbers(myPick){
    document.getElementById("reel1").innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    document.getElementById("reel2").innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    document.getElementById("reel3").innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

userChoice = myPick

function hold(userChoice){
  currentvalue = document.getElementById('reel1').value;
  if(userChoice === getElementById("hold1")){
    document.getElementById("reel1").value="On";
  }else{
    document.getElementById("reel1").value="Off";
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.marginauto {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.button-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
}
.hold-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
.reel-wrapper {
  width: 1280px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.button {
  background-color: white;
}
.reels {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> </title>
  </head>
    <body>
      <header></header>
      <div class="button-wrapper">
        <input type="button" onclick="getNumbers()" value="Start"/>
      </div>
      <div class="hold-wrapper">
        <input id="hold1" onClick="hold();" type="checkbox"/>
        <input id="onoff" onClick="onoff();"  type="checkbox"/>
        <input id="onoff" onClick="onoff();" type="checkbox"/>
      </div>
      <div class="reel-wrapper marginauto">
        <div id="reel1" class="reels"></div>
        <div id="reel2" class="reels"></div>
        <div id="reel3"  class="reels"></div>
      </div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This might help you: [event_onmousedown](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp)

Comment: "message": "ReferenceError: myPick is not defined",  "message": "TypeError: onoff is not a function", and   "message": "ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined",

Answer (score 0):

Some tips for you

1. Define variables and functions before you use them.
2. correct all the errors which are printed in console.
3. Have a look at following code. It locks checked reel. I haven't created a separate function for it. You can try doing that.

```js
var arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];
var f1,f2,f3;

setnum = function() {
  if(document.getElementById("hold1").checked == false){
    document.getElementById("reel1").innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }
  if(document.getElementById("hold2").checked == false){
    document.getElementById("reel2").innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }
  if(document.getElementById("hold3").checked == false){
    document.getElementById("reel3").innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }
  
  
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.marginauto {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.hold-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

.reel-wrapper {
  width: 1280px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.button {
  background-color: white;
}

.reels {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title> </title>
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <input type="button" onclick="setnum()" value="Start" />
  </div>
  <div class="hold-wrapper">
    <input id="hold1" onClick="" type="checkbox" />
    <input id="hold2" onClick="" type="checkbox" />
    <input id="hold3" onClick="" type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <div class="reel-wrapper marginauto">
    <div id="reel1" class="reels"></div>
    <div id="reel2" class="reels"></div>
    <div id="reel3" class="reels"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example itself doesn't work directly, but your problem is general enough that hopefully this will help.

If you want to "hold" a button down, what your going to want to do is watch a couple of events. First, to trigger it, you're going to want to watch for the `mousedown` event. Then, to know when you've let go, you'll want to watch for either the `mouseup` event or the `mouseout` event (which fires when you move the mouse off of an element).

The `mousedown` will also only trigger once, so if you want to repeatedly do something while it's down, you'll want to use `setInterval()` to tell it to do something every x-number of milliseconds.

Something like this would do the trick:

```
const myButton = document.getElementById('myButton'); // replace with what your button actually is

let buttonIsDown = false;
let holdIntervalId = null;

myButton.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
    buttonIsDown = true;
    holdIntervalId = setInterval(hold, 1000); // change 1000 to however many milliseconds you want between trigger
});

function buttonReleased() {
    buttonIsDown = false;
    clearInterval(holdIntervalId);
}

myButton.addEventListener('mouseup', buttonReleased);
myButton.addEventListener('mouseout', buttonReleased);
```